# spring mvc login issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having a problem with this since when i run in tomcat and i put my login details i return to índex page

My controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Atividades.class);

    @Autowired
    AtividadesService as;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;


    @SuppressWarnings("SameReturnValue")
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        //Lista as atividades da semana
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Atividades> atividades = as.listAllAtividades();
        model.addAttribute("atividades", atividades);
        System.out.println(atividades);
        //noinspection SpringMVCViewInspection
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<AppUser> users = userService.listAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
        return userProfileService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method handles Access-Denied redirect.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    /**
     * This method handles login GET requests.
     * If users is already logged-in and tries to goto login page again, will be redirected to list page.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            logger.info("Dentro do login");
            return "redirect:admin/admin.jsp";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method handles logout requests.
     * Toggle the handlers if you are RememberMe functionality is useless in your app.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            //new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
            persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the principal[user-name] of logged-in user.
     */
    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns true if users is already authenticated [logged-in], else false.
     */
    private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }

}
```

UPDATE
I'm seeing that the main problem is mapping??
My debuger results

```
    this = {UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7259} 
 usernameParameter = "email"
 passwordParameter = "password"
 postOnly = true
 eventPublisher = {AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext@7767} "Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 07 19:25:35 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy"
 authenticationDetailsSource = {WebAuthenticationDetailsSource@7957} 
  Class has no fields
 authenticationManager = {ProviderManager@7258} 
  eventPublisher = {ProviderManager$NullEventPublisher@7928} 
  providers = {ArrayList@7929}  size = 2
  messages = {MessageSourceAccessor@7930} 
  parent = {ProviderManager@7257} 
  eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = true
 messages = {MessageSourceAccessor@7958} 
  messageSource = {AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext@7767} "Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 07 19:25:35 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy"
  defaultLocale = null
 rememberMeServices = {PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices@7959} 
  tokenRepository = {$Proxy58@8029} "com.gmc.dao.HibernateTokenRepositoryImpl@47ea4ebc"
  random = {SecureRandom@8030} 
  seriesLength = 16
  tokenLength = 16
  logger = {Log4JLogger@8031} 
  messages = {MessageSourceAccessor@8032} 
  userDetailsService = {WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator@8033} 
  userDetailsChecker = {AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker@8034} 
  authenticationDetailsSource = {WebAuthenticationDetailsSource@8035} 
  cookieName = "remember-me"
  parameter = "remember-me"
  alwaysRemember = false
  key = "2be34eb5-f085-4b16-9fe6-323a43438b12"
  tokenValiditySeconds = 86400
  useSecureCookie = null
  setHttpOnlyMethod = {Method@8038} "public void javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setHttpOnly(boolean)"
  authoritiesMapper = {NullAuthoritiesMapper@8039} 
 requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher = {AntPathRequestMatcher@7960} "Ant [pattern='/login', POST]"
  matcher = {AntPathRequestMatcher$SpringAntMatcher@8042} 
  pattern = "/login"
  httpMethod = {HttpMethod@8044} "POST"
  caseSensitive = false
 continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication = false
 sessionStrategy = {CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy@7961} "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy [delegateStrategies = [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@5cf78323, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@38443d7e]]"
  logger = {Log4JLogger@8046} 
  delegateStrategies = {ArrayList@8047}  size = 2
 allowSessionCreation = true
 successHandler = {SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler@7962} 
 failureHandler = {SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@7963} 
 logger = {Log4JLogger@7964} 
 requiredProperties = {HashSet@7965}  size = 0
 filterConfig = null
 beanName = "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2ad5e5aa"
 environment = {StandardServletEnvironment@7777} "StandardServletEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment,class path resource [application.properties]]}"
 servletContext = {StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext@7771} 
ProviderManager.authenticate(Authentication) = {UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7870} "org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7b107287: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@c44e5eb1: Username: abc@xxxx.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 08F76148E72EE07D33F6DF293982955A; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN"
 principal = {User@7551} "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@c44e5eb1: Username: abc@xxxx.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN"
  password = null
  username = "abc@xxxx.com"
  authorities = {Collections$UnmodifiableSet@7641}  size = 1
  accountNonExpired = true
  accountNonLocked = true
  credentialsNonExpired = true
  enabled = true
 credentials = null
 details = {WebAuthenticationDetails@7739} "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 08F76148E72EE07D33F6DF293982955A"
  remoteAddress = "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
  sessionId = "08F76148E72EE07D33F6DF293982955A"
 authorities = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@7880}  size = 1
  0 = {SimpleGrantedAuthority@7644} "ROLE_ADMIN"
 authenticated = true
request = {HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@7952} 
 response = {HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper@7953} 
  request = {RequestWrapper@7975} "FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5c7e8107]"
  httpSessionExistedAtStartOfRequest = true
  contextBeforeExecution = {SecurityContextImpl@7977} "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication"
  authBeforeExecution = null
  this$0 = {HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository@7978} 
  logger = {Log4JLogger@7979} 
  contextSaved = false
  disableUrlRewriting = true
  OnCommittedResponseWrapper.logger = {Log4JLogger@7979} 
  disableOnCommitted = false
  contentLength = 0
  contentWritten = 0
  response = {FirewalledResponse@7980} 
 request = {RequestWrapper@7975} "FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5c7e8107]"
  strippedServletPath = "/login"
   value = {char[6]@7988} 
   hash = 1448719514
  strippedPathInfo = null
  stripPaths = true
  request = {RequestFacade@7984} 
response = {HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper@7953} 
 request = {RequestWrapper@7975} "FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5c7e8107]"
  strippedServletPath = "/login"
  strippedPathInfo = null
  stripPaths = true
  request = {RequestFacade@7984} 
   request = {Request@7989} 
 httpSessionExistedAtStartOfRequest = true
 contextBeforeExecution = {SecurityContextImpl@7977} "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication"
  authentication = null
 authBeforeExecution = null
 this$0 = {HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository@7978} 
  logger = {Log4JLogger@7990} 
  contextObject = {SecurityContextImpl@7991} "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication"
  allowSessionCreation = true
  disableUrlRewriting = true
  isServlet3 = true
  springSecurityContextKey = "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"
  trustResolver = {AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl@7993} 
 logger = {Log4JLogger@7979} 
  logger = {Logger@7999} 
  name = "org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper"
 contextSaved = false
 disableUrlRewriting = true
 OnCommittedResponseWrapper.logger = {Log4JLogger@7979} 
 disableOnCommitted = false
 contentLength = 0
 contentWritten = 0
 response = {FirewalledResponse@7980} 
username = "abc@xxxx.com"
password = "ebspma"
authRequest = {UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7725} "org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8a47d5b4: Principal: abc@xxxx.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 08F76148E72EE07D33F6DF293982955A; Not granted any authorities"
 principal = "abc@xxxx.com"
 credentials = "ebspma"
 details = {WebAuthenticationDetails@7739} "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 08F76148E72EE07D33F6DF293982955A"
 authorities = {Collections$EmptyList@7740}  size = 0
 authenticated = false
```

My httpSecurity configuration

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("dba/**").hasRole("DBA")
            .antMatchers("user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("func/**").hasRole("FUNC")
            .antMatchers("registo","index", "login").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");


}
```

My web folders and my security config (web based)

[image: folders]

Comment: Any error on browser console?Disable csrf and try. csrf().disable().But don't disable it on prod env.

Comment: this method userProfileService.findAll() returns a right list?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace, not only the first line.

Comment: Right now the problem is not that method  userProfileService.findAll(), teh problem is i don't get successfull login